# Calculations within the text control that are in the new repeat control

Tags: orbeon

I am developing an eform in Orbeon form builder. Here I am using a repeater (new repeat) control. Within that control there are many rows of text controls. I want to make some calculation with the values which the user will insert in those controls. Suppose two columns are there "number of items" and "Unite price". Inside which there are many rows, i.e. user will insert values dynamically.

Next to this repeater control is a text control where the total amount must be displayed without any button event.

E.g. suppose a repeater structure which is like a table:

```
column name(Number of items---unit price)
 first value(1 ----100)
 second value(5----200)
```

Total amount must be displayed on the text control as 1100. The number of grid may increase depending upon the user (here it is 2).

Comment: Are you creating the form with Form Builder or by writing XForms "by hand"? If the latter, I assume you are using a 4.0 milestone build, right? (Repeats are not supported in Form Builder in 3.9.)

Answer (score 0):

To find out the total cost, i could not come up with the normal calculation tricks. So i used a pretty small XQuery to solve the problem.

I do not know if you are using a form builder or Xforms coding "by hand", but i develop using "by hand". Below is the complete Xforms Code which u can run it on Orbeon Xforms Sandbox.

```
<xhtml:html xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
    xmlns:f="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/formatting"
    xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:xxforms="http://orbeon.org/oxf/xml/xforms"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    >

    <xhtml:head>

        <xforms:model xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" id="main-model">

          <xforms:instance id="form-instance">
            <form>
                <sale>
                    <number-of-units>1</number-of-units>
                    <unit-price>100</unit-price>
                </sale>
                <sale>
                    <number-of-units>2</number-of-units>
                    <unit-price>500</unit-price>
                </sale>
            </form>
          </xforms:instance>


        </xforms:model>
    </xhtml:head>

    <xhtml:body>

      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                Total price:
            </td>
            <td>
                <xforms:output value="sum(
                                        for $i in instance('form-instance')/sale
                                            return $i/number-of-units * $i/unit-price
                                        )
                                        " /> 
            </td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </xhtml:body>
</xhtml:html>
```

Browser Output:

[image]

In case if you are using form builder, you can pick up the result expression and use for calculate attribute of bind definition if you want.

Expression:

```
sum(
    for $i in instance('form-instance')/sale
        return $i/number-of-units * $i/unit-price
    )
```

Good Luck!